# Why we use argc -1?

Tags: c, parameters, argv, argc

This is a function to reverse a given arguments , why we used `argc - 1` in this context,as long as there's not null to compare in int type, is it to subtract file name from count ? and if you could show other use of argc - 1 that would be great.

```
int     main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;

    i = argc - 1;
    while (i > 0)
    {
        printf("%s", argv[i]);
        putchar('\n');
        i--;
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: If an array has length n, the last element is stored at index n-1 because arrays are indexed from 0.

Comment: `argv` is an array of `char*` that has `argc` elements. As arrays in C start with the index `0`, they run up to `argc - 1` (the last element).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read the previous answers and I notice that they try to give you another way to re-write your code instead I'm going to explain to you how `argc` and `argv` works.

as you may notice why we declare the argument in the main function we do this :

```
int main(int argc, char **argv
```

this means that when you try to launch the executable program you should give it some addition arguments.

1. `argc` is the number of arguments being passed into your program from the command line
2. `argv` is the array of arguments.

and you should know that the array starts from 0 this means that if you want to print the last arguments in the array you can do this:

```
printf("%s\n", argv[argc - 1]);
```

for example:

I have a program that takes a list of arguments and prints one by one and every argument followed by newline `\n`.

the code:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    int j;

    while (argv[i])
    {
        j = 0;
        while (argv[i][j])
        {
            write(1, &argv[i][j], 1);
            j++;
        }
        write(1, "\n", 1);
        i++;
    }
}
```

NOTE: this program doesn't use any built-in function (except `wite`).

if you try to compile this code and execute it:

```
➜  Desktop gcc test.c 
➜  Desktop ./a.out test test1 test2
./a.out
test
test1
test2
➜  Desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just badly written code, it is nothing to study or learn from. By applying common sense, we can re-write this as:

```
for(int i=1; i<argc; i++)
{
  puts(argv[argc-i]);
}
```

Assuming we don't want to print `argv[0]`.

Comment: agreed, very bad written, by the way I'm allowed to use no for loop neither any other function other than write, printf and putchar I should recreate them in order to use the them.

Comment: @RidaEN-Nasry So you are taking some strange class where the goal is to become bad at C programming? Anyway, rewriting the code in worse ways is trivial: `int i=1; while(i<argc) { printf("%s\n", argv[argc-i]); i++; }`

Comment: @RidaEN-Nasry Good or bad, it's useful to understand that every `for` loop can theoretically be rewritten using `while`, and vice versa.  This point is discussed at the end of [this course notes page](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx3e.html).

Comment: @Lundin re-writing a built-in functions in C, make you understand how those functions work so when you use them next time you have an Idea how/why you use them.. so the class he's taking is a good one specially if he really want to learn how those function works

Comment: @SteveSummit Obscure loops having complex end conditions or complex iteration etc, or being weird in general, is a massive source of bugs. As is the plague known as "write the code as complex as you possibly can". Often for the sake of showing off some obscure C knowledge. The end result is bugs, worse optimization and worse cache performance. So it's not a matter about `for` vs `while` but a matter about common sense vs insanity and discipline vs sloppiness.

Comment: @DarkSide77 Not sure what you mean. What built-in functions are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

For comparison, here are two more ways to write the same loop.

Method 2:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    for(i = argc - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    }
}
```

Method 3:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i = argc;
    while(--i > 0)
    {
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Now benchmark all versions posted and keep the one with best results. My money is on the most simplistic and readable loop.